# C# trim a certain argument

Tags: c#, arguments, trim

Alright so I have this code and the issue is that when I use this, the findplayer argument is repeated in the text. I'm guessing it's because the text uses args which is all arguments which is a problem because i want the text to be multiple words.

```
var plr = player.Manager.FindPlayer(args[0]);
string text = string.Join(" ", args);
plr.Manager.Chat.Say(plr, text);
```

Any ideas to fix this? Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to skip the first argument, you can do:

`string text = string.Join(" ", args.Skip(1));`